# Qtreewidget item change color to Icon in Qtreewidgetitem

Tags: qt, qtreewidgetitem, qicon

how change background icon inside a qtreewidgetitem dinamically:
Some code example..

```
if item.text(0)=="INL"
   item.icon(0).setBackground(Qt.green)
else:
   item.icon(0).setBackground(Qt.yellow)
```

I want only icon background not all item (icon+text)..
[image: test]

Comment: You can use font icon and to change their color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [delegate item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html) and override the [paint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html#paint) method.

Example

h file

```
class MyItemDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
public:
   MyItemDelegate(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
   void paint ( QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & oStyleOption, const QModelIndex & index ) const;

}
```

cpp

```
void MyItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &oStyleOption, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    // Apply for column 0
    if (index.column() == 0) {  

       // background color
       Qt::GlobalColor eColor;

       // Get table data
       if (index.model()->data(index).toString() == "INL")
           eColor = Qt::green;
       else
           eColor = Qt::yellow;

       painter->save();

       // background rect size (icon size 16x16 + padding)
       QRect oRect(oStyleOption.rect.x() + 2, oStyleOption.rect.y() + 6 , 16, 16);

       // background color
       painter->fillRect(oRect, eColor);
       painter->restore();    
   }
   return QItemDelegate::paint(painter,oStyleOption,index);
}
```

to set the item to your table use [setItemDelegateForColumn](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn)